# How to stay in the final page after registration in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to know how to stay in the booking page.The scenario is,

"If i go to booking page and is not a customer then when i click "Book Now" button a login popup
shows and i can login and it will stay in same page.  But the problem is, if i am not a customer and i want to register then i am being redirected to register page, as the 'url' will change how to retain the data and go back to final booking after successful registration.

Any suggestions will be Appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Why don't you keep booking details info in session or a service and populate when you are back to booking page

Comment: add a url query parameter returnTo=finalBooking?